# Default Java on Windows machine

Tags: java, java-8, windows-10

I have a Windows 10 x64 machine. I had Open JDK 10. My `JAVA_HOME` points to Open JDK 10 location. **My `Path` variable has `%JAVA_HOME%/bin;` part.**

Then I installed Java 8.
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Java installer changes `Path`.

```
 C:\Users\user>set Path 
 Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;OTHER_STUFF_WITHOUT_JAVA
```

Now in command line `java -version` points to Java 8.

```
 C:\Users\user>java -version
 java version "1.8.0_202"
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)
```

But `JAVA_HOME` is still pointing to Open JDK 10.

```
C:\Users\user>set java_home
JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk\jdk-10.0.2
```

My goal is to have Open JDK-10  as default Java.

This is not a duplicate 
[Default Java Path on Windows Machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650841/default-java-path-on-windows-machines)
because there is no answer for me.

Comment: JAVA_HOME is not same as PATH. so set JAVA_HOME separately.

Comment: What is the contents of PATH after installing? I've noticed the java installer can add path values to the start of the path, which could preempt your own `%JAVA_HOME%/bin;` value.

Comment: What's your goal, Java 8 or Java 10?

Comment: My goal is to have open JDK-10 as default Java on my machine.

Comment: @JornVernee, yes, Java installer changes `Path`. Now it starts with `C:\Users\user>set Path
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;`

Comment: If you have both C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath and %JAVA_HOME%\bin in your Path, you are probably overriding one of your java. You can remove " C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath" entry

Comment: The easiest way to have several JDK and be sure to point towards the good one, is to avoid using the java installers. You should just unzip the JDKs in a folder and then modify your JAVA_HOME and PATH accordingly. You could also have several JAVA_HOME like JAVA_HOME_8 and JAVA_HOME_10 pointing to their respective JDK folder and make your JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME_10% so you can change easily.

Comment: @JulienRevaultd'A... Great, you can answer here. What about if I have already installed one Java from installer?

Comment: Just zip the directory where it is installed, now uninstall the JDK, and then just unzip in some folder and point your JAVA_HOME towards the unzipped folder if you want.

Comment: I never understood why there are installers for the JDK, when a zip is everything you need... I started hating them when I didn't had install rights, and required different JDKs :-/

Comment: @Roland - Now I will not use installers... I agree.

Comment: If I remember correctly there wasn't a zip available for Oracle JDK 8? So you may need to... (it is rather cumbersome to unpack the installer _and_ having the sources and everything unpacked ;-)).... but you can install it, copy it to another location and uninstall it ;-) (if you have the appropriate rights)

Comment: You're right, thats unfortunatly what you must do on windows machines :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Post comment as the answer for readability)

The easiest way to have several JDK and be sure to point towards the good one, is to avoid using the java installers. You should just unzip the JDKs in a folder and then modify your **JAVA_HOME** and **PATH** accordingly. You could also have several JAVA_HOME like **JAVA_HOME_8** and **JAVA_HOME_10** pointing to their respective JDK folder and make your **JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME_10%** so you can change easily.

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` is only relevant to applications which actively use it (by convention). The JVM does not care. Most applications supporting `JAVA_HOME` also offer other means of configuration. So unless truly needed for a particular application, the simpler solution is just not to set the `JAVA_HOME` variable.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way i just found out is that the java 8 installer creates a new environment PATH entry:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath**

This will point to the latest installed JRE or JDK(i.e. the last in JDK or JRE) using the installer method.

So if your JAVA_HOME points to the JDK 10 OR JRE 10 just go to the Environment Variables and remove:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath**

From the PATH variable.

Then the values you used for JAVA_HOME will become effective.

*This worked for me after installing java 8 and i had installed java 12*